# How would you design "compressed" circle like this one?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS6.

I found some SVG circle with this modified path:

[image]

How would you draw this in Illustrator? Each "side" is equal. I don't think I need to edit path manually, else every side will look weird and not symmetrical.

Which feature would you use?

Comment: [Watch this tutorial Video](https://youtu.be/v5cpO4F2YgY)
[![Sample video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5EWs.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5EWs.jpg) Use the above video tutorial to draw a compressed circle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Starting with a Circle > duplicate it
- **Menu Effect** > **Distort Transform** > **Zig-Zag**

[image: ZIG ZAG]

- **Menu Object** > **Expand** to get the new shape vector anchor points
- Add a Stroke to increase the gap difference with the original circle. This step is because the *Star Shape* is smaller than the original circle. Could be replaced by reducing a little the shape size proportionally to the center.

[image: Stroke]

- **Menu Object** > **Expand** to get the stroke shape vector anchor points
- **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Select the stroke and the shape > **Pathfinder** > **Minus Front**

[image: Minus Front]

- Center this shape with the original circle
- Select both shapes > **Pathfinder** > **Intersect**

[image]

**Result**

[image: final]

Comment: Why do you "Menu Object > Expand" every time? What's the benefit? It seems to works the same without Expand it (which basically select with more precision, right?)

Comment: If you don't expand you don't get the shape vector anchor points, it would be the circle with an effect. If you don't expand, you can not apply a Pathfinder because the shape still being the same.